# How to fill text span from bottom-left, meanwhile wrapping around text span at bottom-right?

Tags: css

What HTML markup and CSS can achieve filling the "aaa" `span` from the bottom-left, meanwhile wrapping around the "BBB" `span` at bottom-right:

```
+------------------------------+
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
| aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa \\\\\\\\ |
| aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa \\\\\\\\ |
| aaa aaa aaa //// BBB BBB BBB |
+------------------------------+
```

(The characters `\\\` and `///` represent two different whitespace areas).

Something like:

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="aaa">
        aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
        <span class="BBB">BBB BBB BBB</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Example:

```
+------------------------------+
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
| the quick        BBB BBB BBB |
+------------------------------+

+------------------------------+
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
| the                          |
| quick brown      BBB BBB BBB |
+------------------------------+

+------------------------------+
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
| the quick                    |
| brown fox        BBB BBB BBB |
+------------------------------+

+------------------------------+
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
| the quick brown              |
| fox jumps        BBB BBB BBB |
+------------------------------+

+------------------------------+
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
| the quick brown fox          |
| jumps over       BBB BBB BBB |
+------------------------------+

+------------------------------+
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
| the quick                    |
| brown fox jumps over         |
| the lazy dog     BBB BBB BBB |
+------------------------------+

+------------------------------+
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
| the quick brown fox          |
| jumps over the lazy          |
| dog and then     BBB BBB BBB |
+------------------------------+

+------------------------------+
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
| the quick brown fox \\\\\\\\ |
| jumps over the lazy \\\\\\\\ |
| dog and then//// BBB BBB BBB |
+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this one is to absolutly position the ".aaa" SPAN to the bottom and then float the ".BBB" SPAN to the right. I believe this is the best your going to get:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <span class="aaa">
            aaa
            <span class="BBB">BBB BBB BBB</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 30%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}
.aaa {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.BBB {
    float: right;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery to demonstrate how the content flows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $(".aaa").prepend(" aaa"); 
    }, 500);
});
```

JSFiddle to see it all in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rqtt3cv1/2/

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty close, but the problem is that in your current solution the lowest line (to the left of `BBB`) is sometimes blank, whereas in my example it is **always** filled. My design requirement is that the lowest line must always contain some text - *except* under the circumstance that a single word is longer than the space to the left of `BBB`. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Right. I don't see anyway of doing this in CSS then. The only way is to come up with some JavaScript solution.